# How to save timestamp in UTC format for Audit fields @CreatedDate, @LastModifiedDate in Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

This is my Base Class for Entities with audit fields. For fields @CreatedDate, @LastModifiedDate, by default it is saving my system time. My requirement is to save timestamp in UTC.

Does anyone have a solution of this?

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EntityListeners;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedBy;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedBy;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import lombok.Data;


@MappedSuperclass
@Data
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name="last_modified_datetime")
    private LocalDateTime lastModifiedDateTime;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name="created_datetime")
    private LocalDateTime createdDateTime;

}
```

Comment: You can use: spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone = UTC

Comment: It didn't work exactly but it gave me idea though. Thanks .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is problem of time zone. use this code for spring boot.

```
@PostConstruct
public void setTimeZone() {
   TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
}
```