# auto update last updated field with utc time on insert and update

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

Say I have the following DB TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE REQUEST
(

    ID            BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    LABEL         NVARCHAR(32)          NOT NULL,
    STATUS        NVARCHAR(10)          NOT NULL,
    ERROR_MESSAGE NVARCHAR(200),
    LAST_UPDATED  DATETIME              NOT NULL
);
```

and a JPA Entity Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REQUEST")
public class Request implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "LABEL")
    private String label;

    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Status status;

    @Column(name = "ERROR_MESSAGE")
    private String errorMessage;

    @Column(name = "LAST_UPDATED")
    private LocalDateTime lastUpdated;

}
```

Is there a way I can update the `lastUpdated` field as UTC timestamp on every insert or update to rows automatically with Spring JPA without having to use setters for every update:

```
entity.setLastUpdated(nowTimeUTC())
repo.save(entity)
```

Answer (score 0):

use [Auditing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.0.DATAJPA-580-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/auditing.html)

```
@LastModifiedDate
@Column(name = "LAST_UPDATED")
private LocalDateTime lastUpdated;
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60073200/how-to-save-timestamp-in-utc-format-for-audit-fields-createddate-lastmodified) to set up your timezone